# Instantiate List from LinkedList constructor in Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I needed to implement a function that has return type of `List<List<String>>` and I tried lots of ways to instantiate the variable to return:

This does not work:

```
List<List<String>> result = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();

error: incompatible types: LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> cannot be converted to List<List<String>>
```

Finally, this worked:

```
List<List<String>> result = new LinkedList<>();
```

Compiler is fine with this and the code works well.

However, I don't understand why the first statement does not work and why the second one does.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: @JBNizet I have a feeling that, this is not the exact dupe.

Comment: It is: the OP tries to initialize a List<List> with a List<LinkedList>, where LinkedList is a subtype of List. Same problem as trying to initialize a List<Animal> with a List<Dog>, where Dog is a subtype of Animal. The dupe explains why that is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The first way was syntactically incorrect and correct is

```
    List<LinkedList<String>> result = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
```

And in second case, you are probably using JDK 7 or + where type inference happening with diamond operator.

To understand fully read [`Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)

For example, consider the following variable declaration:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

> In Java SE 7, you can substitute the parameterized type of the constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>):

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```